# How to enable remote access in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've tried to grant privilege for root and did flush privelege, but when I check `SHOW GRANTS`, I got this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*******' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

In phpMyAdmin user accounts page, I see this message:

> A user account allowing any user from localhost to connect is present.
>   This will prevent other users from connecting if the host part of
>   their account allows a connection from any (%) host.Documentation

What does this mean, and how could this stops me from access database remotely?

Comment: if you will try access remotely, then your user will looks like `'root'@'x.x.x.x' `  where `x.x.x.x` is your current IP address. so you can't connect at all, because mysql will know only `'root'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

Having a `'user'@'localhost'` account means that remote connections are not accepted.

If you want to be able to connect from anywhere, the grant should be on `'user'@'%'`, where the `%` is a wildcard matching any IP address.

Comment: I've tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' ` but it doesn't work. Is there any conflicts between `localhost` and `%`?

Comment: @Nick what error you see? also check /var/log/mysqld.log